# Get fetched result in different arrays by joined tables

Tags: php, query-builder, cakephp-4.x

I would like to make a `Post` object containing an instance of its associated table `User` and the easiest would be if I could access user results and post results separately.

The query:

```php
$query = $this->connection->newQuery()->from('post');
$query->select(
    [
        'post.message',
        'post.created_at',
        'user.name',
        'user.email',
        'user.role',
        'user.status',
    ]
)->join(['table' => 'user', 'conditions' => 'post.user_id = user.id']);
$postsRows = $query->execute()->fetchAll('assoc');
```

The query above outputs an array of the result rows and I have no way to know if the column is from the `user` table or `post` table.

```
$postsRows = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'message' => 'This is a test post',
    'created_at' => '2021-01-01 00:00:01',
    'name' => 'Admin Example',
    'email' => 'admin@example.com',
    'role' => 'admin',
    'status' => 'active',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'message' => 'This is another test post',
    'created_at' => '2021-01-01 00:00:01',
    'name' => 'User Example',
    'email' => 'user@example.com',
    'role' => 'user',
    'status' => 'active',
  ),
)
```

Naturally I can make aliases for each column

```php
$query = $this->connection->newQuery()->from('post');
$query->select(
    [
        'post.*',
        'user_name' => 'user.name',
        'user_email' => 'user.email',
        'user_role' => 'user.role',
        'user_status' => 'user.status',
    ]
)->join(['table' => 'user', 'conditions' => 'post.user_id = user.id']);
$postsRows = $query->execute()->fetchAll('assoc');
```

But then I have to go through them and split the array manually later, I can't alias the post column names as I use the expression `*` and it won't work when joining the same table.

I guess what would be ideal would be the following output. Is something like this possible?

```php
$postsRows = array(
    0 => array(
        'post' => array(
            'message' => 'This is a test post',
            'created_at' => '2021-01-01 00:00:01',
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'name' => 'Admin Example',
            'email' => 'admin@example.com',
            'role' => 'admin',
            'status' => 'active',
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'post' => array(
            'message' => 'This is another test post',
            'created_at' => '2021-01-01 00:00:01',
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'name' => 'User Example',
            'email' => 'user@example.com',
            'role' => 'user',
            'status' => 'active',
        ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: Of course you know which column comes from which table. you wrote the query. And no you cannot flip a switch and make the result look like what you want

Comment: What's the problem with loading the entire records for these? I often see people limiting what columns they're selecting, but it causes problems more often than solving them. (There are certainly some cases where limiting columns is useful or even necessary, but I think they are very limited.)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Just looking at the output array how can I determine which column comes from which table programmatically? I need to create a Post object and a User object and for this I have to know which value came from which table.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Well this has nothing to do with my problem (or probably I'm missing out on something) but there would be an issue and that is that there are columns with similar names. For instance, both `user` and `post` have a `created_at` column. In querybuilder fetched result, the first one (so, `post` `created_at`) gets overwritten by the `user` `created_at` and in this particular use case only the post `created_at` relevant. Or is there a way around that apart from defining manually select columns with aliases? I need to have both `created_at` results and know which one is from which table

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/odan/slim4-tutorial/issues/33)

Comment: If you had associations set up correctly between the various tables, you could just do `$posts = $this->Posts->find()->contain('Users')`, and then the results would be Post entities which have all the columns from the posts table (e.g. `$post->created_at`), plus a `user` property that has an entity with the columns from the users table (e.g. `$post->user->created_at`). This is how Cake code is generally written; I'm not sure why you're making so much more work for yourself.

Comment: @GregSchmidt apologies, I forgot to add that I only work with the query builder cake/database package, not the ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/odan/slim4-tutorial/issues/33), the workflow that interests me is more "use case" based, and then it doesn't make sense to do what I requested (as it would kind of be reinventing ORM [which I did first](https://github.com/odan/slim4-tutorial/issues/33#issuecomment-840474305)).

What works out for me is creating specific DTOs with high cohesion like `UserPost` in which case the origin of the table is not relevant as fields are selected individually, precisely.